# Enabling access for local host?

Tags: c#, server

I've made a simple test code to make a local server with C#, according to following page. [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/485182/Create-a-local-server-in-Csharp) Of course I know C# isn't the ideal language for making local server, but majority of the code was already done in C#, so I had no other choice.

I'm using httpListener, and I added my IP to the prefixes as following.
`_httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://@@@.@@@.@@@.@@@:5000/");`

but it shows response too long error code.

The code worked and I can see the page running on `localhost:5000/` from my desktop.

I wanted to make it accessible from other devices, so I made new inbound rule to open port 5000. But when I try to access it with IP address even from the desktop itself, it returns bad request: invalid hostname error. I guess I'm missing something I have to do. Most of the

Comment: By the way "localhost" means loopback. It represents the range 127.0.0.0/24,all of which point to your own machine _only_. Can you include more details of how you are hosting this solution, and if it's ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core, or some other solution (e.g. [`HttpListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netcore-3.1))?

Comment: Are you trying to connect in LAN or WAN?

Comment: You should just need to add another prefix for your LAN or public IP, as far as I'm aware. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Please show us the `response too long error code`.

Answer (score 0):

See if the following helps

**Using `http://localhost:5000` - Admin Run Time - No Firewall Rule**

- http://localhost:5000/ - works on running machine only
- http://192.168.1.127:5000/ - Bad Request

**Using `http://localhost:5000` - Admin Run Time - Firewall Rule PORT 5000 allowed**

- http://localhost:5000/ - works on running machine only
- http://192.168.1.127:5000/ - Bad Request

**Next bit comes with security warnings from microsoft as we are listening widely** 
**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.8**

**Using `http://+:5000` - Admin Run Time - No Firewall Rule**

- http://localhost:5000/ - works on running machine only
- http://192.168.1.127:5000/ - works on running machine, does not work on other device

**Using `http://+:5000` - Admin Run Time - Firewall Rule PORT 5000 allowed**

- http://localhost:5000/ - works on running machine only
- http://192.168.1.127:5000/ - works on running machine, works on other device

**Using `http://192.168.1.127:5000/` - Admin Run Time - Firewall Rule PORT 5000 allowed**

- http://localhost:5000/ - Does not work
- http://192.168.1.127:5000/ - works on running machine, works on other device